# PHP using external anonymous function inside class

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have two files. In file1.php I have an anonymous function:

```
    $myfunc = function($params) {
         // do something
}
```

in file2.php I have a class and inside this class I need to use the function defined in file1.php.

I am using global to declare the variable assigned function from file1.php and then calling it like this:

```
class {
// properties
  mymethod(){
    global $myfunc
    $myfunc()
 }
}
```

This gives me an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string

I tried to look elsewhere but there aren't any blogs explaining how to do this or others who've had the same problem.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why is it anonymous if you need to call it by name later? Why not just name the function? You’re basically  trying to do that anyway.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice. The reason I'm using an anonymous function is to be able to use the closure syntax to gain access to a class instance that was created outside the function I want to call. I didn't want to use the global keyword inside the function so I chose to use anonymous function closures instead, but it seems like I might need to use it anyway. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with WordPress. This is really just a PHP question, so is off topic here.